# What does "No lines in buffer" mean when editing via scp?

Tags: netrw, ssh

I was using `vim scp://` and `e scp://` to edit remotes files. Sometimes I failed to open and got message `--No lines in buffer--`. What does mean and how I should solve?

Comment: No lines in buffer just means that there was nothing in the file (buffer) it tried to open. It's possible that failing to open them just caused vim to think there were no lines in it for some reason. Couldn't tell you why you're failing to open them or how to resolve that issue though.